# Twilio Notification for queue

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-php

Can I have a notification if a caller leaves a queue?

I'm trying to make a real-time queue size counter using PHP, how will I be able to count the current queue size? I already have a trigger if someone calls, but what if the caller leaves the queue?

For example, a user decided to stop the call while in queue or when a client already picked up his/her call.